# Time keeping table for employee clocking

Tags: database-design, time

I must make a time clocking application for employees. Every employee is identified by a ticket which is scanned when they arrive and leave the building. Unfortunately I can not know for sure if they arrive or leave because of a law(they work in underground).

I am thinking of grouping somehow of two rows into one to get the worked hours. The only problem I have using this approach appears if the ticket is scanned two time at arrival or leaving.

How would you solve this problem?

Until now this is the structure of TicketUsages table
[image]

Comment: How/when do they get this ticket? Per working day? Can they leave on a different day then when they enter (overnight work)? Is `created_at` supposed to be the arrival time and `updated_at` the leave time?

Comment: To handle double scanning you might introduce a "grace period" where a scan is ignored if it's within a short period of time from the previous scan. You could implement this on the application side or roll up (group) records to some interval (e.g. 1 minute) when querying. Having said that, the question seems off-topic for this site.

Comment: They got a ticket per working day. Yes, they can. `created_at` and `updated_at` are set at the same value( they are set by the framework). How can I pair two consecutive row to get the working hours?

Comment: Clocking in and clocking out will not be consecutive rows in the table.  You'll have to order the select by ticket_id, created_at.  This will put the pairs together, since you say they get a new ticket_id every work day.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to implement such task I would use a clean-up technique.

I would go through recent data (let's say yesterday's) and remove (or mark `useless`) all suspicious rows. Later I can use a simple `JOIN` to read "arriving" and "leaving" rows as one:

```
SELECT *
FROM TicketUsages arriving
JOIN TicketUsages leaving
    ON arriving.ticket_id = leaving.ticket_id
    AND arriving.created_at < leaving.created_at
WHERE from_unixtime(arriving.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-09-14'
    /** Optional: AND NOT arriving.useless AND NOT leaving.useless **/
```

The clean-up procedure only has to find tickets with a different count then 2. This will show you the invalid tickets:

```
SELECT ticket_id, count(*)
FROM TicketUsages
WHERE from_unixtime(arriving.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-09-14'
GROUP BY ticket_id
HAVING count(*) != 2
```

Then you just have to decide what to do with the rows. If there are more then 2 you can probably only keep the first and the last. But it's up to you what to do if only 1 row is returned.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately I got a last hour requirement, they can enter and exit the building multiple times with the same ticket.